# Map multiple properties of an object to dictionaries in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary, firebase

I have a User class with 13 properties (first name, last name, email, etc). I would like to display all of this information in a Contacts-like card in my app. I am not trying to access my (or any other users) contacts in the Contacts app, I simply want to create a view that looks like it.

My first attempt was to create everything manually. I create a UITableView with static cells and manually populated each cell with the correct data. However, this is really tedious and does not allow for expansion.

I would prefer it if I could use reusable cells and populate the data dynamically. I would like to grab all of the properties of User and put them into dictionaries and then store those dictionaries in an array for each user and then put all of those arrays in one array. The latter two items I can figure out. What I can't figure out is how to get all of the properties into dictionaries.

*From ContactCardTVC:*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fullNameTextField.text = user.firstName+" "+user.lastName
        positionTextField.text = user.position
        emailTextField.text = user.email
        phoneNumberTextField.text = user.phoneNumber
        birthdayTextField.text = user.birthday
        dateStartedTextField.text = user.dateStarted
        teamTextField.text = user.team
        serviceTextField.text = user.service
        scheduleTextField.text = user.schedule
        editButtonItem()
        TitleNavigatonItem.title = user.firstName+" "+user.lastName
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
```

*From AdminTVC:*

```
var users = [User]()


  func fetchUsers() {
        let userRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
        userRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
            var newUsers = [User]()
            for user in snapshot.children {
                let users = User(snapshot: user as! FDataSnapshot)
                newUsers.append(users)
            }
            self.users = newUsers
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SeeContactCardSegue" {
            if let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ContactCardTVC {
                if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    let user = users[indexPath.row]
                    destVC.user = user
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*From User:*

```
class User {
    var firstName = ""
    var lastName = ""
    var email = ""
    var birthday = ""
    var team = ""
    var schedule = ""
    var service = ""
    var position = ""
    var phoneNumber = ""
    var dateStarted = ""
    var profileImgURL = ""
    var notes = ""
```

*This is what I have now in the storyboard:*
[image]

I would like for the keys to populate the information in blue and the values to populate the actual information in those cells.

Comment: Why do you need to use a dictionary? Isn't using an array of `User` easier and access them like this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: `users[indexPath.row].name`?

Comment: Well, that's what I have now but because I'm not using reusable cells, I'm not allowing for the in-app creation of another category. I would have to go in and manually create it in Xcode every time. Right? I want to able to have that capability. Is that possible? To use reusable cells with this model?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to create new sections during runtime? Even so, it's still possible to reuse the cells without a dictionary. I don't see why you would need that. For example, you could use a multi dimensional array like: `[[User]]` to have multiple sections.

Comment: That's true for sections but I don't need sections. Those are rows with one label as a category and one label as the information. The static cells were created and populated manually. I want to know how to do it dynamically with reusable static cells. I also want to populate each cell (both the category label and the info label) dynamically (that's where I figured the dictionary would come in handy). I'm aware that I could make a Firebase call to get the key each time but that doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: I'm still unsure as what you exactly want from reading your comments. But looking at your screenshot, it seems you want a view showing a picture and the rows with the information. A section header doesn't have to be a "row with a few labels". You can use a custom `UIView` as your section header showing as many pictures / labels as you want. Then you can show the rows of each section (each user) with the information you want.

Comment: The first row (the picture and two labels) are not what I am referring to. I am referring to the rows beneath that. I don't need sections or a section header. I just want to populate the rows of information using reusable cells instead of manually created rows. I created all of those rows in the storyboard manually. I want to have one reusable prototype cell and use the properties of User to populate those rows. I don't know how to populate the information without manually referencing each property. Is that the only way to do it? Does that help?

Comment: The question is unclear; a Prototype cell would be one that defines a structure that other cells can conform to. Are you wanting to use the existing label in each cell as a key to retrieve a value from the user class?

Comment: I understand prototype cells. The image I posted was my attempt at manually programming each cell (see ContactCardTVC code) but that seemed really tedious and I was trying to figure out if there was a way to do that dynamically. I think your question is basically on the right track for what I want. If I could populate both labels using property name and value, I would prefer that.